# Using Moment with Angular and TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, momentjs

I'm new to TypeScript and it's been a while since I've done any serious JavaScript development, so I may be missing something obvious.

I'm trying to use Moment in an Angular 1 app with TypeScript.

I'm using Angular 1.6.5, Moment 2.17.1 and TypeScript 2.17.1.  I have Angular typings installed from the npm `@types\angular` package.  Intellisense etc for Angular is working in VS Code.

I've posted the sample code to GitHub here: https://github.com/kevinkuszyk/moment-angular-typescript

### The first error

My sample app runs in the browser, but the TypeScript compiler complains that it can't find Moment:

```
app/controller.ts(3,20): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'moment'.
app/controller.ts(6,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'moment'.
```

### Try using a /// compiler directive

To fix this, I tried adding the following `///` compiler directive:

```
/// <reference path="../node_modules/moment/moment.d.ts" />
```

But that doesn't fix the TypeScript compiler:

```
app/controller.ts(5,20): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'moment'.
app/controller.ts(8,30): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'moment'.
```

### Import Moment

Next I tried importing Moment using the instructions from their [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/typescript/):

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

But this makes TypeScript generate a different erorr:

```
app/controller.ts(13,5): error TS2686: 'angular' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

### Import Angular

I also imported Angular.  This fixes TypeScript:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
```

But now the app doesn't run in the browser:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at controller.js:2
```

### Use Require.JS

Finally I tried adding Require.JS, but this just causes a different runtime error:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "moment" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (require.js:1433)
    at requirejs (require.js:1794)
    at controller.js:2
```

### Questions

1. Have I missed anything obvious here?
2. What's the best practice for referencing `d.ts` files which are shipped with the main package on npm rather than a separate `@types` package?
3. How do I make this work without using an external module loader?

Comment: you can do that using direct add moment.min.js file

Comment: My `index.html` is already referencing `moment.js` from the `node_modules` folder.  If I switch that over to `moment.min.js` I still get errors from the TypeScript compiler.

Comment: can you try to declare moment variable like this 'declare var moment: any;' before @Injectable() or @Component

Comment: That fixes usage like `let foo = moment()`, but using the `moment.Moment` interface still produces a compiler error.  Also there's no intellisense in VS Code for `moment()` with this fix.

Comment: @KevinKuszyk I'm having the exact same issue.  Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @KevinKuszyk Having the same problem as well. Any new ideas?

Comment: @Darthg8r I just had another look at this, and spotted some GitHub issues I didn't see before.  Please see my answer below with an interim fix that worked for me.

Comment: @Ace7k3 please see my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like this is a known issue with Moment's `d.ts` file (see issues [#3763](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3763), [#3808](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3808) and [#3663](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3663)).

While we wait for an official fix, this worked for me.

Change:

```
export = moment;
```

to this:

```
declare module "moment" {
    export = moment;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly declaring the `@types` scoped package to typesRoot in your `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": false,
        "typeRoots": [
            "./node_modules/@types"
        ]
    }
}
```

Ensure the type definitions are installed properly in `node_modules/@types/...` and that your TypeScript compiler is up to date.

Comment: Thanks @kyranjamie.  I'm on the latest TypeScript (2.1.6).  Moment ships with it's `d.ts` in the main package, so this fix doesn't work I'm afraid.

Comment: Strange, just works for me.  How about if you add the moment project as well to the `typesRoot` array?

Comment: You may be on to something.  If I add `./node_modules/moment` to the `typesRoot` array I get `error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'locale'.` and the same for `min` & `src` from the compiler.

Comment: Moment does also has a definition under `@types`. Perhaps that might work

Comment: It does have an `@types` package, but it's a stub. In `@types/moment@2.13.0` all you get is a `readme.md` with the message `This is a stub types definition for Moment (https://github.com/moment/moment).
Moment provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/moment installed!`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to very slowly bring a dated project up to modern standards, and so I struggled with trying to get the other solutions to work while this same issue happened to me intermittently.

Ultimately, I decided to replace Moment with one of the maintained alternatives, as suggested on the Moment website: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

I highly recommend anyone reading this do the same.  Moment was great, but it's time to say goodbye.