# Type definition file momentjs import into Angular2+

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I'm facing an issue that looked like fixed according to topics I read. But not for me...
I'm trying to include moment into my **Angular2** components.

```
npm install --save moment
```

In my package.json :

```
"moment": "^2.18.1"
```

In my component.ts files :

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

But when I build my app, i'm still getting the error :

```
TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'moment'.
```

I checked the installed package, I've got a ***moment.d.ts*** file at the root.

My tsc version : **2.3.2** and I'm using webpack btw.

Any idea ?

--

**EDIT WITH ANSWER :**

The configuration is actually OK. The problem came from @types/moment i've previously installed, which were loaded because of :

```
"typeRoots": [
   "node_modules/@types"
 ]
```

**Solution :**
**Remove @types/moment folder and @types/moment in the *tsconfig.json***

Comment: what package are you using webpack, angularcli like that?

Comment: I'm gonna edit my answer. I'm using webpack (with the ng2-admin project :) )

Comment: please refer to the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42227596/using-moment-with-angular-and-typescript

Comment: It's refering to old moment version, it doesn't help. Now moment provides its own types definition.

Comment: Found the solution. I've edit my question